# Read Only filestream seems to lock file on network share

Tags: vb.net, file, filestream

I have a problem in that when we run a section of code to open a file stream which accesses a file on a network share and immediately close it (a document previewer) which is read only, if another process tries to access the file they get the error "This file has been locked by another user"

I've ruled out the possibility that it was a 3rd party control and I can reproduce the problem with the following code 90% of the time

```
Using stream As Stream = New FileStream(_strLastDocumentPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite)
  stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin)
  stream.Close()
End Using
```

Do you have any ideas what might be causing this and if so - how to fix it? My assumptions at the moment are that it may be related to the Garbage Collector and when that runs.

Comment: It's been many months so you may no longer care, but some more information would be needed such as how the previewer opens and closes the file (is it the same pattern as your repro code or is the repro just what fails to open?) and do you mean that two previewers are not able to overlap their reading or do you mean that even after closing (and disposing) another process is still unable to open the file some time later?  Or is another process failing to open for writing while a previewer still has it open for reading?  Also, what is the OS of the network share?